# How to make user install same version of depency A as depency B is using?

Tags: node.js, npm

I used the variables in the title of this topics, but I also have the live example.

The alpha version **1.5.0-alpha.0** of the package **@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-localization-japanese** depends on version **1.5.1** of [@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions):

```json
{
  "name": "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-localization-japanese",
  "version": "1.5.0-alpha.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions": "1.5.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions": ">=1.5.0 <1.6.0"
  },
  // ...
}
```

If to install the correct versions of both packages, both distributables will be put directly below **node_modules/@yamato-daiwa**:

[image]

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions": "1.5.1",
    "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-localization-japanese": "1.5.0-alpha.0"
  }
}
```

Now let's assume that I made a mistake and installed the version **1.5.0** of **@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions**. In this case, the additional instance of **@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions** will be put below **node_modules/@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-localization-japanese/node_modules**.

[image]

The localization will be applied anymore, but there also will be any error, so if it was not the experiment, I could not undestrand the cause.

How to make use install the appropriate version of **@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions**? Is more strict **peerDependencies** like  "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions": "1.5.1" will be enough?

Comment: I don't think it really answers your question, but I want to suggest you check
the [check-dependecies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-dependencies) package to verify if the conditions of the package are met. Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted - you have 2 installations `@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions` - in main app's `node_modules` and in `@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-localization-japanese` `node_modules`. Your application uses the package from its `node_modules` folder, but the localization uses another instance from its `node_modules`. That's why localization is not working.

To prevent this, you should enable [`strict-peer-deps`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#strict-peer-deps) property in the project's `.npmrc` file. `npm` will treat non-compatible peer dependencies as a failure.